# SharedFlow always missing out on the initial value

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to understand how `SharedFlow` works, but notice that the 1st emitted value is always not collected by the consumer..

Have a look at the code snippet below:

```
val producer = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()
val consumer = producer.asSharedFlow()

scope.launch {
    val counter = AtomicInteger(1)
    while (counter.get() <= 3) {
        val value = counter.getAndIncrement()
        producer.emit(value)
        println("produced: $value")
        delay(1000)
    }
}

scope.launch {
    consumer.collect {
        println("consumed: $it")
    }
}
```

With the code, I expect the output to be like below (may not be in exact order):

```
produced: 1
consumed: 1
produced: 2
consumed: 2
procuded: 3
consumed: 3
```

Instead, `consumed: 1` is always missing as a result of this code.

Can someone please explain to me what is happening here?

Comment: @MadhuBhat I called `getAndIncrement()`, not `incrementAndGet()`...

Comment: `producer.emit(1)` is called before consumer starts collecting so it misses the first emission. Add `replay = 1` as argument to the `SharedFlow` to re-emit the most recent value.

Comment: @GlennSandoval why would it missed the first emission when the 2nd value is not emitted yet?

Comment: That's how SharedFlow works. It's like a Publish Subject in RxJava. Its replay cache is meant to consume elements emitted before the time of subscription.

Comment: @GlennSandoval now it make sense to think of it like `PublishSubject`, thanks!